# NGINX: putting request details on custom 404.json returns

Tags: python, json, nginx, custom-error-pages

For 404s and 500s/502s/504s errors, I'm returning a custom JSON error page:

```
{
    "response":
    {
            "status": "EXCEPTION_404_NOT_FOUND",
    }
}
```

In my sites-enabled/service_nginx.conf, I set it up like this:

```
error_page 404 /404.json;
location /404.json {
    internal;
    root /temp/error_response_templates;
}
```

And this is working fine. That is, the JSON is returned every 404.
But I want to add the request or some request details to the returned JSON.
For example, for http://service.com/param1/param2/, if in case 404 is encountered,
I want to include the param1 and param2 in the returned JSON. Like this:

```
{
    "response":
    {
        "status":"EXCEPTION_404_NOT_FOUND",
        "param1":<param1 value>,
        "param2":<param2 value>,
    }
}
```

Is this possible? If yes, can someone help me how to do it?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6):

You can setup something like this for each error code:

```
  error_page 404 @404_json;

  location @404_json {
    default_type application/json;
    return 404 '{ "response": { "status": "EXCEPTION_404_NOT_FOUND",
    }, "message": "Not Found"}';
  }
```

Or load the error message from a file, e.g.:

```
try_files /404.json =404;
```

It's recommended to [avoid using variables](http://nginx.org/en/docs/faq/variables_in_config.html) in templates (for performance reasons).